# FAIL -Getting error in tomcat7: War file "WhitePagesAddressLookup.war" cannot be uploaded if context is defined in server.xml

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, jakarta-ee, war

I have tried to get rid of the 404 tomcat error. After quite a bit of research  I realise that my tocat7 manager is not deploying my war file. I am getting this error:   FAIL - War file "WhitePagesAddressLookup.war" cannot be uploaded if context is defined in server.xml  Can anyone tell me why this is so? I have put my .war file inside of my eclipse folder and outside on my desktop both but placement does not affect the "fail" error.

Comment: Your `war` file should be in tomcat's webapps directory

Answer (score 0):

By reading the error you get, I guess it's because the context `WhitePagesAddressLookup` is defined in the `<TOMCAT_HOME>/conf/server.xml`, which is not compatible with dynamic deploying. Better stop Tomcat, remove the correspondant `Context` node from the `server.xml`, restart Tomcat, and try to re-deploy it.

Comment: Because I was deploying the war file twice I was getting this error. Thank you for all your help !